# Trouble with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Is my following calculation true?

$e^{a+ib}e^{\overline{a+ib}}=e^{a+ib}e^{a-ib}=e^{2a}$? for a,b real numbers
or in general, what is $\overline{{z}^{w}}$ if $z,w$ are complex numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes $\color {green}{e^{a+ib}\bar{e^{a+ib}}=e^{a+ib}e^{a-ib}=e^{2a}} $ is true 
Hint:$$z^w=e^{w \ logz}$$  $$log z=\ln(|z|+\arg(z))$$
Edit :$e^{\bar{z}}=e^{x}\ cos (y)+i\ sin(-y)=e^{x}\ cos (y)-i\ sin(y)$ and  $\bar{e^z}={e^{x}\ cos (y)-i\ sin(y)}$

Comment: Lipschitz: yes  notice to definition of exp(z)